# Show user avatar if logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, passport.js

I have a MERN stack setup with passport js and passport local set-up fot the login handling. The login and register methods work fine. Now I wanted to be able to show the user's avatar like stackoverflow does (Upper right corner). When the user login I set a cookie with a boolean value that I use to change how the button get displayed. 
On Login:

```
    fetch(GLOBALS.API_URL + "/user/login", {
      ...
    })
      .then(response => {
        ...
      })
      .then(data => {
        setSubmitting(false);
        console.log(data);
        //THIS IS THE PART 
        if (data.message === "User logged in correctly") {
          Cookies.set("logged-in", true);
          history.push(data.redirect);
        }
      })
```

And then I just read the cookie and if it is true I will display an icon otherwise "Log in"

```
const [profile, setProfile] = React.useState(false);    
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(Cookies.get("logged-in"));

    if (Cookies.get("logged-in") === "true") {
      console.log("ciao");

      setProfile(true);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    profile ?
      <>

          <AccountCircle />
      </> : <>
          Log In
      </>
  );
```

Instead of the icon I wanted to display their avatar, now my questions is, when I login should I send back some data like username, avatar link so I can use it to for the client side or this is not secure? If this is not great any tips would be apriciated.

Comment: Only upon login you have all those data, before logging in how would you determine which data belong to the user?

Comment: The cookie would be set only when the login and if the press logout it would get deleted, but I don't know if this is secure